# File size limit in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, scala, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to check the size of a file uploaded in a Play application (2.0.3).

I tried both Scala and Java controllers, but I've got the same weird behaviour every time ... I manage to detect that the file is too large, but when I try to return a response, the request hangs forever and the user is not aware that the request is not valid.

In Java :

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.MultipartFormData.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024)
pulic static Result upload() {
  if(request().body().isMaxSizeExceeded()) {
    return badRequest("Too much data!"); // this is not returned
  } else {
    ok("Got body: " + request().body().asText()); 
  }
}
```

In Scala :

```
def upload = Action(parse.maxLength(10 * 1024 * 1024, parse.multipartFormData)) { request =>
    request.body match {
        case Left(MaxSizeExceeded(length)) => {
            Logger.error("MaxSizeExceeded")
            BadRequest("Your file is too large, we accept just " + length + " bytes!")
        }
        case Right(multipartForm) => {
            // Do stuff to handle the file
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML template :

```
@(httpPath: java.lang.String) @main(httpPath) {

    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data", 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'id -> "form") {

        <div id="well" class="well">

                <h1>Upload</h1>
                <div id="formGroup" class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="file">Select file : </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input id="file" name="file" type="file" style="display: none" /> 

                        <div class="input-append">
                            <input id="txtFile" type="text" class="required" readonly="true"/>
                            <span class="btn" onclick="$('#file').click();">Browse</span>
                        </div>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                             $('#file').change(function() { 
                                 $('#txtFile').val($(this).val()); 
                             }); 
                         </script>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Upload</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Log :

```
2014-04-30 16:46:44,791 - [[trace]] - play - New I/O  worker #4 - Serving this request with: Action(parser=BodyParser(maxLength=1048576, wrapping=BodyParser(multipartFormData))) -
2014-04-30 16:46:44,996 - [[trace]] - play - play-akka.actor.promises-dispatcher-60 - Invoking action with request: POST /upload -
2014-04-30 16:46:44,998 - [[error]] - application - play-akka.actor.actions-dispatcher-10 - MaxSizeExceeded java -
2014-04-30 16:46:44,999 - [[trace]] - play - play-akka.actor.actions-dispatcher-10 - Sending simple result: SimpleResult(400, Map(Content-Type -> text/plain; charset=utf-8, Set-Cookie -> )) -
```

I saw that other developers faced the same problem (eg https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/wuXnoXN5GZ0). 
Is this a known issue in 2.0.x? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to try your code in Play 2.2.x and see if it works there? That will tell us whether this is a problem that has been fixed since Play 2.0.x.

Comment: I already tried with 2.0.8, but same problem.

Unfortunately, I have to use 2.0.x version for this application, but I'm going to try anyway.

Comment: Even in 2.2.1, the request hangs.

What is the proper way to end a request when the file size is too large and you want to terminate the request?

Comment: can you show your view template (html file) ?

Comment: I just edited the question with the template

Comment: @cpoissonnier I have tested the Scala code you have and it works just ifne in 2.2.2 and 2.2.1. I've tested with Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu. Maybe you could run your app having logging set to TRACE? What browser are you using and on what system are you?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 with Firefox and Ubuntu.

Setting the log to TRACE didn't really help, the behaviour seems to be ok (cf. edited question)

Comment: And if you try to generate a file and upload it with curl? e.g. `dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=1 bs=12582912 && curl -i -F name=test -F filedata=@file.txt http://localhost:9000`, this should tell us what server sends back. You can also check if my code which works for me works for you https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/279703/issue_23365670.tar.gz

Comment: My bad, when I migrate to 2.2.1, it works, but it can be very slow with very large files (that's why I thought that the upgrade didn't change anything). Thanks for your app, it works like a charm.

It seems that it is indeed a problem with Play 2.0.x that have been fixed in 2.1.0. I planed a play upgrade. Thank you for your time and your help !

Comment: I didn't help so much with your problem, but I'm glad to hear that it's fixed in Play now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By upgrading Play version to 2.2.1, the problem disappears.

I tried with the last 2.0.x version published (2.0.8), the bug is still present.

Apparently, it has been fixed in 2.1.x.